# Location not being saved to config.yml

Tags: bukkit

I'm trying to save a Location in a config.yml, and when he steps onto that location, it provokes an action. However, that is not happening.

Sorry for including the entire code, but I thought it would be essential for this kind of program.

Main class:

```
public class Turrets extends JavaPlugin{

    ArrayList<String> playersThatShouldPlaceBlock = new ArrayList<String>();

    HashMap<String, String> turretName = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String turretsMsg = ChatColor.RED + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Turrets" + ChatColor.RED + "]" + ChatColor.GOLD + ": ";

    public int waitForPlacement;

    public void loadConfig() {

        this.getConfig().addDefault("Turrets.", null);

        this.saveConfig();

    }

    public void onEnable(){

        new CreateTurretEvent(this);
        loadConfig();

    }

    public void onDisable(){
        loadConfig();
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args){

        final Player p = (Player) sender;

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("turret")){

            if (args.length < 2){
                p.sendMessage(turretsMsg + ChatColor.RED + "Invalid usage! /turret [create or delete] [name]");
                return true;
            }
            else if (args.length >= 2){
                if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("create")){
                    if (args[1] != null){
                        p.sendMessage(turretsMsg + ChatColor.GOLD + "Place a block and YOU will become a turret when you step on it!");

                        playersThatShouldPlaceBlock.add(p.getName());

                        turretName.put(p.getName(), args[1]);

                        waitForPlacement = Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable(){

                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                p.sendMessage(turretsMsg + ChatColor.RED + "You waited too long so the action was cancelled!");
                                playersThatShouldPlaceBlock.remove(p.getName());

                            }

                        }, 600L);


                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }


        return false;
    }

}
```

Listener class:

```
package me.mortadelle2.turrets;

import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockPlaceEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerMoveEvent;


public class CreateTurretEvent implements Listener{

    Turrets getter;

    public CreateTurretEvent(Turrets plugin){
        plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
        getter = plugin;
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void playerPlacesBlockToBecomeTurret(BlockPlaceEvent e){

        Player p = e.getPlayer();

        if (getter.playersThatShouldPlaceBlock.contains(p.getName())){
            p.sendMessage(getter.turretsMsg + "That block is now turretified!");
            getter.getServer().getScheduler().cancelTask(getter.waitForPlacement);
            getter.playersThatShouldPlaceBlock.remove(p.getName());

            Location blockLocation = e.getBlock().getLocation();

            getter.getConfig().set("Turrets." + getter.turretName.get(p.getName()), blockLocation);
        }

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void playerStepsOnTurret(PlayerMoveEvent e){

        Player p = e.getPlayer();

            if (getter.getConfig().contains("test")){ //I will add something more specific than test later
                p.sendMessage("This is a test");
            }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1: spelling mistake (this problem has been edited out of the question at [question revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32442621/3))**

You seem to have misspelled `onDisbale(){`. When a plugin is disabled, it will run the method `onDisable()` on your plugin. In your case it isn't run because you don't have a method with that exact signature.

**How to prevent this in the future**

By added `@Override` at the start of a method, you are saying that it MUST override  a existing method found in a parent class. This can be used like:

```
@Override
public void onDisable() {
```

**Problem 2: Implementation of the PlayerMoveEvent isn't finished yet**

Notice, stackoverflow isn't a "we write code for you service"

By analyzing your code, you are saving your config in the following format:

```
playername:
    turretname: (location object)
```

**Step 1: changing the location saving**

The bukkit configuration doesn't work properly with Location objects, you should change your location saving to

```
getter.getConfig().set("Turrets." + getter.turretName.get(p.getName())+ ".world", player.getLocation().getWorld().getName());
getter.getConfig().set("Turrets." + getter.turretName.get(p.getName())+ ".x", player.getLocation().getBlockX());
getter.getConfig().set("Turrets." + getter.turretName.get(p.getName())+ ".y", player.getLocation().getBlockY());
getter.getConfig().set("Turrets." + getter.turretName.get(p.getName())+ ".z", player.getLocation().getBlockZ());
```

This changes the configuration to store the world, x, y and z seperately

**Step 2: parsing the config at the PlayerMoveEvent**

Because we changed our config format, it will be easier to detect what turret we are standing on at the PlayerMoveEvent

We will the following method of detecting what block we are standing on at the PlayerMove

1. Check if the turret exists inside the configuration

   ```
   ConfigurationSection sec = getter.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("Turrets."+getter.turretName.get(p.getName())); 
   // Todo: check if the player exists inside getter.turretName
   if(sec != null){
       ....
   }
   ```
2. Parse the configuration to check if the location is found

   ```
   Location loc = event.getPlayer().getLocation();
   if(loc.getBlockX() == sec.getInt("x") && loc.getBlockY() == sec.getInt("y") && loc.getBlockZ() == sec.getInt("z") && loc.getWorld().getName().equals(sec.getString("world"))) {
       event.getPlayer().sendMessage("This is a test");
   }
   ```

This should fix the problem you are having. The following improvements can be done:

- Only call the player move code when the player changes the block
- Use more descriptive variable names, for example `getter` should be renamed to `main` or `plugin`

Comment: Holy hell! I'm a derp!

Comment: This didn't fix it unfortunately though. I'm still having a problem where nothing happens when you step on the block.